# What is with the %'s in these lines of code

Tags: python-3.x

Hi im writing a dice rolling program in python and have come across this line of code. Can you tell me what it is and how it works please? Thanks.

```
print ("The dice you threw was a %d-sided dice" %dice_type)
print ("You rolled a %d" %score)
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) with `%d`, which is replaced with the integer expressed as a string. `%` indicates that it's a placeholder for a value and `d` indicates that the integer should be converted into a string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response that's cleared things up for me.